# Perl scripts that has the same function as Unix Command "history"?

Tags: perl, unix

Is it possible to write a Perl script to grab the history of Unix commands? Which means write a Perl scripts that has the same function as Unix Command "history"?

I tried to use tcsh history but the history does not contain latest Unix commands. The latest will only be available after I close the current xterm. Is there a way to solve it without closing the xterm?

I saw something in other post which is PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a', how to use it? T.T

Thanks.

Comment: This may be a little off topic - but why are you using tcsh? perhaps something like bash or zsh would better suit your needs. Also, just as an on topic, have you set your history variables and such? because I though tcsh had nice history support ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen

```
 Term::ReadLine::Gnu
```

http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=all&query=term+readlin+gnu

on cpan?

SO has a

```
 readline
```

tag for it and the other implementations.

Answer (score 2):

You can control this behavior by editing your `.tcshrc` file found in your home directory.

If you alias `precmd`, that will be run before each prompt is shown.  The command you want is `history -S` which will force a save of your current history.
Assuming that you're running multiple terminals at once, you'll also want to set `savehist` so that it merges all of the histories rather than just overwriting.  Without the merge option, the history file would be overwritten with your current terminal's history, but as soon as you went to another window, the history would be overwritten with *that* terminal's history.

So, assuming you want to keep 500 lines of history (merged), here are the two lines you need to add into your `~/.tcshrc` file.  Note, unless you've changed `histfile`, your history will be found in `~/.history`:

```
set savehist = (500 "merge")
alias precmd "history -S"
```

In closing, I'd strongly suggest (in agreement with @Mimisbrunnr) that you look at using either `bash` or `zsh` as they've incorporated the best parts of `tcsh` along with the power of the Bourne shell (`sh`) leaving out all of the weaknesses of `csh`.

Oh... and if you want a perl script to get the history, use something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $hist_fh, '<', "$ENV{HOME}/.history"  or die "Cannot open history file: $!\n";

my @history;
while (<$hist_fh>) {
    chomp;
    next if /^#/;  # Skip timestamps
    push @history, $_;
}
close $hist_fh;

print "Now I have my history in an array, the latest thing I did was: $history[-1]\n"
    if @history > 0;  # show latest command if we were able to read the history file
```

Comment: Hi!!! Thanks so much for giving me such useful suggestions and advises, I really appreciate that!                                  I have a question, well all I'm trying to do is implement everything using Perl script without typing any command in Unix, meaning is it possible to implement that two lines which is to added into the ~/.tcshrc file in Perl script using different syntax or any other method.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment.  If you're trying to get shell history (in this case `tcsh`), then you must activate the writing of that history through the shell... i.e. it's a feature of the shell.  If you were instead asking about writing your own command-line prompt with history, then you could use `Term::Readline::Gnu` to create a prompt, get user input, save history, search it, etc.  In the latter case here, you're writing your own shell or interactive interface to your program.

Comment: Let me take time to study Term::Readline::Gnu first. So there is no Perl script/syntax that has the same function as "history -S"?

Comment: or maybe the direction of my questions is wrong, because actually what I want to do is "history | grep keyword", just because it takes quite some steps if i wanna grep many types of keywords, so I want it to be automation, which I write a Perl script to do everything, so whenever I want to see those certain commands, I will just use the Perl script to do it for me.

Comment: The question you're asking is vague.  Are you trying to force a shell to save its history?  Or are you writing your own command line interpreter for which you want its history?   If the former, then no, because that's a shell built-in, and it affects the internals of the shell itself.  There is no external history tracking.  `history -S` is an internal command to the shell telling it to save its history instead of waiting until the shell ends.

Comment: Aha.  Sounds like your best bet would be to just do a `history | my-perl-script` which would have the perl script read "history" from standard input and then does whatever you're interested in doing.  If you reformulate your question that way, submit it again, and I'm sure all sort of folks (maybe even me) will try to get that solved.  Be sure to say what in history it's looking for, and what you expect the actions or output to be.

Comment: oh? history | my-perl-script, may I know how it works? because as long as I can have the list of history commands, i should be able to match the keyword and print out.